# Megalomania vs narcissism?

Tags: ambiguity

They look very similar.
It's hard for me to discern the difference.
Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone can be a narcissist and not be a megalomaniac, but a megalomaniac is always a narcissist, by my understanding of the two words.

Comment: Egomaniac and narcissist are closer in meaning than narcissist and megalomaniac?

Comment: Marin, this question might best be asked on [Cognitive Sciences](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/), which deals with psychology, etc. Good luck!

Comment: Sounds fair, can someone move it to that sub-forum?

Comment: I'm always puzzled by these "What's the difference between A and B?" questions when A and B have completely different meanings. A narcissist is in love with himself. A megalomaniac wants power above all else. How can you not see any difference?

Comment: @Marin. Please state the paerts of the definitions of the words that lead to your confusion.

Comment: Isn't a megalomaniac also in love with himself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A close reading of a dictionary would probably separate these two. In essence, megalomania is about power. A megalomaniac wants to dominate people. Narcissists think only about themselves: other people are unimportant to them.

A narcissist might be happy in a place where there were no other people, but his every need was catered to. A megalomaniac might sacrifice his own comforts in order to achieve what he really wants - power over people.

I'm only talking about the common usages of the words here. Both also have clinical psychiatric definitions which are somewhat different.